# RabbitMQ send and receive the message in PHP

Tags: php, rabbitmq

I need a little help here.
I work with RabbitMQ "composer.phar require php-amqplib/php-amqplib" library

I need to send and receive the same message:

The sending is OK, nut the receiving take a lot of time (4-5 minutes) and I got this error:

```
Broken pipe or closed connection in /home/solegreen/public_html/xxxxx/lib/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php:171
```

The full code is here (send):

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/lib/vendor/autoload.php';
require 'lib/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AMQPStreamConnection.php';
require 'lib/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AMQPSSLConnection.php';
require 'lib/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Message/AMQPMessage.php';

define( 'CERTS_PATH', realpath( __DIR__ . '/lib/' ) );

$response = array(
    'message_sent'     => false,
    'message'          => '',
    'received-message' => '',
);

$ssl_opts = array(
    'cafile'           => CERTS_PATH . '/ca-cert.pem',
    'local_cert'       => CERTS_PATH . '/client-cert.pem',
    'local_pk'         => CERTS_PATH . '/client-key.pem',
    'verify_peer'      => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
);

$host     = '40.000.0.000';
$user     = 'user_name';
$password = 'user_pass';
$port     = 12021; // secured.

// Send message.
$connection = new PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPSSLConnection( $host, $port, $user, $password, $vhost = '/', $ssl_opts );
// $connection = new PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection( $host, $port, $user, $password );

$channel = $connection->channel();

$channel->queue_declare( 'request-queue', false, true, false, false );

$message_content = '{"type": "user_information","meter_id": "73505064136"}';

$msg = new PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage( $message_content );

$channel->basic_publish( $msg, '', 'request-queue' );

$response['message']      = "[x] Sent 'user_information json' to request-queue.";
$response['message_sent'] = true;

$channel->close();
$connection->close();
```

Receive:

```
// Receive the message.
$connection = new PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPSSLConnection( $host, $port, $user, $password, $vhost = '/', $ssl_opts );
$channel    = $connection->channel();
$channel->queue_declare( 'reply-queue', false, true, false, false );

$received_message = '';

$callback = function ( $reply_msg ) {
    $received_message             = $reply_msg->body;
    $response['received-message'] = $received_message;
};
$channel->basic_consume( 'reply-queue', '', false, true, false, false, $callback );

while ( $channel->is_open() ) {
    $channel->wait();
}

$channel->close();
$connection->close();

print_r( $response );
die();
```

What am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: Unrelated to the problem: is `lib/vendor` managed by Composer? Because, if so, you don't need all the other require statements.

Comment: How it can be related to composer? I send - client receive and send me back. If's fine. But response time is so huge

Comment: Disregard my comment then. Composer is the industry standard to manage libraries and it uses `vendor` as name for package directory, thus my confusion.